# printing application for zebra S4M using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, zebra-printers

I would like to create an application that will print labels/barcode to a Zebra S4M label printer.

I need some kind of simple tutorial or a sample program which I can study.

My file is like

```
4826520125 NAME 200.00
```

Where 4826520125 is the Barcode, NAME is the description and 200.00 is the price

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need should be here : [Zebra Card Printer SDKs](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/developer-tools.html)

Comment: the tools are there but how to program is not listed. I would like to learn how, like a beginner. Thanks..

Comment: Everything should be in the SDK. From the SDK website "A SDK reference manual describing the programming functions that control operations and deliver data for Zebra card printers."
If you want someone to build you a finished solution I think you might be wrong here ;)